# Index omits the associated page number for most index entries; this affects just one document

Tags: microsoft-word

For one document the page number is almost always missing from the index. This seems to be document-relevant, because correct indexing is possible for other documents. The TOC page numbering is correct and page numbers are present on each page.
I have repaired (Open and Repair) the associated document and repaired MS Office 2016 - there was no improvement.
I have deleted (and recreated) the index - there was no improvement.
I saved the document in Word 2003 format and recreated the index - there was no improvement.
Is there anything else I can try?

Partial index:

[image: screenshot for partial index]

Here is a [link to a sample document with the problem](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AqTZzjvx6q9zmXkOwfGDKa-ccnCx?e=vUUC2z).

Comment: Is there something different about this document, such as many sections, or the font used for the index entries?

Comment: Not really. I managed to create an index for an earlier version of the document, although it has been extensively reformatted since then. I just tried whether I could recreate a correct index for this earlier version - no problem. The current version was created by merging the differences between two documents - this might have corrupted the document, but Libre Office Writer had no problem in creating a correct index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the Index Field in a working document with the field that is not working.

**Alt+F9** to toggle view of Field codes.

You can simply copy a working Index field from one document to another.

Here is my [article on the Microsoft site on working with fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258).

Comment: Thanks Charles. I copied the Index field from the working document to the "corrupted" document. It correctly displays the index from the working document, but updating the index produces the same result; this time without any page numbers.

Comment: Can you post a link to a sample document with (1) a few problem entries and (2) the index field that is not working.

Comment: Can I send you the document? It is quite large, approx. 220 pages (the index is also large. 7 pages).

Comment: I have managed to create a small subset of the "corrupt" document that exhibits the same behaviour with regard to the index. 
I have also done some tests on this subset document: when I mark new index entries, they alone are shown correctly in the index.

Comment: Curious! Could you put a link to the sample problem document in an edit to your original question?

Comment: How, please, can I link my Word document (approx. 1MB)?

Comment: This article shows how to prepare a document link for sharing/viewing: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258

Comment: I have copied my sample document to OneDrive and have tried to share with
https://superuser.com/users/1219214/charles-kenyon
but I get the message that the recipient is invalid

Comment: You need to get a link for the file. You post that here.

Comment: The link: "C:\Users\Rudd\OneDrive\regexIntro21-12-20mini.docx"

Comment: Read the article I linked. That is a link to a web page. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258 You need your file in a cloud location, not your hard drive. You need to create a link to the cloud. Read my page. For example, this is a link to a document on a cloud location. It is a zip folder containing a document. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7npy3d6t6blby2r/OrganizerQAT.zip?dl=0

Comment: Sorry. I did read your article, what I oversaw was how to share my OneDrive document (I am not very familiar with OD).
This link should be OK: 
https://1drv.ms/w/s!AqTZzjvx6q9zmXkOwfGDKa-ccnCx?e=vUUC2z
Although this opens in a Word "mini-editor" with limited functionality, I assume that you can save a "proper" document. If not, I will look into the Dropbox solution.

Comment: I looked at your document and could not figure it out. I'm putting the link in your question so others are likely to see it. At this point, I would recommend stripping out your entries and re-marking them. Here is a temporary link to a document where I started doing that: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ufc13c6k0n6h6vf/deleteme%20stripped%20regexIntro21-12-20mini.docx?dl=0  Here is my writing on indexes. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Index

Comment: Thanks, I was coming to the same conclusion that I would have remark my index entries, unfortunately there are many 100. I also did some experimenting with the faulty entries. Incorrect index entries always have the form: {XE "entry:"}. If I remove the :, the index is displayed with page number; if I add an: to a previously correct entry, the index is displayed without page number. What I do not know is how my document became corrupted!

Comment: With hidden text displayed, you can use Find to find the Index entries. You would be searching for ^dXE and ^d XE. Otherwise, I would unlink the Index field converting your Index to text. Then use that as a guide to look for the problem entries. When done, delete the text Index and recreate the Index field.

Comment: It sufficed to only delete the terminating colon from the index entries. The document index is now correct.

Comment: Glad you got it worked out.

Comment: Thanks for your help.